# Duda respecto a un error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matemáticas, sympy

estoy incursionando en el tema de derivadas en python pero recientemente me esta surgiendo un inconveniente, resulta que al momento de ingresar la funcion me da el siguiente error:

> ---
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>   ----> 3 ecuacion = eval(input("Digite la funcion a evaluar:"))
>
> in ()
>
> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

```
from sympy import Symbol

ecuacion = eval(input("Digite la funcion a evaluar:"))
ecuationdev = ecuacion.diff(i=Symbol('x'))

print(ecuationdev)
```

La verdad si alguien puede decirme que estoy haciendo mal estaria eternamente agradecido porque debo entregar un trabajo muy pronto respecto a derivadas y estoy muy perdido con ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando llamas a `input()`, éste te retorna simplemente una cadena de caracteres.

Cuando haces `eval()` sobre la cadena retornada, el intérprete python intentará interpretar esa cadena como si fuera código python. Cualquier cosa que el usuario haya escrito, será interpretado en ese momento como si estuviera escrito en el lenguaje python y fuera una línea más de tu programa. El resultado de esa evaluación será asignado a tu variable `ecuacion`.

Eso significa que el usuario podrá poner por ejemplo: `2**3+4` y eso será interpretado como una expresión python cuyo resultado en este caso será 12 y eso sería lo que iría a la variable `ecuacion`.

Si el usuario en cambio escribe algo como `2*x**3 + 3*x`, entonces para python es como si tu programa contuviera la línea:

```
ecuacion = 2*x**3 + 3*x
```

Ya que la variable `x` no existe en este punto, te aparece el error que has podido ver: `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Para arreglar este caso particular, basta que esa variable exista antes del input. En el caso de `sympy` esa variable debe ser un símbolo para que luego pueda usarse en operaciones como la derivada. Por tanto tu programa quedaría así:

```
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
ecuacion = eval(input("Digite la funcion a evaluar:"))
ecuationdev = ecuacion.diff()

print(ecuationdev)
```

**Nota**. Esto resuelve el problema particular de que el usuario use una `x` como parte de su expresión, pero no el problema general, ya que el usuario podría usar otras letras que seguirían dándote error. Además, es necesario que el usuario introduzca una expresión python válida, como por ejemplo `5*x`, ya que si el usuario en cambio escribe algo como `5x` que puede resultar razonable para un matemático, `eval()` producirá igualmente un error al no ser `5x` una expresión python válida. Quizás te interese mirar la documentación de [parse_expr](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html)

Comment: Se que tu respuesta es de hace 6 años, pero la doy por buena, sinceramente había olvidado por completo este post. Gracias!

Comment: Esto igual bate algún récord XD